# how to move a listview item up or down with a button click

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, button, indexing

I have items in a listview and I want to know how to add 2 buttons one that makes the item move up in the list and one that make the item move down in the list. I figure out how to do it with listboxes but I cant figure out or find where to do it for list views and help is appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check out the Listview.Items.Remove and Listview.Items.Insert methods:

```
listView1.Items.Remove(selectedItem);
listView1.Items.Insert(newIndex, selectedItem);
```

Dealing with the changing index (when you remove a ListViewItem, the indexes of the list items which come after the selected item all change by one) can be a pain. Also, you will need to manage what happens when you promote or demote an item past the top or lower bounds of the item indexes.

Hope that gets you started.